# Node update npm error - missing file or directory

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have been trying to update the version of node on my box. When I attempt to do this either by npm update node, npm install node, or npm update node -g I get the following error (path depending on if global or local)

```
npm ERR! encent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'path/home/node_modules/nodebin/node'
npm ERR! encent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'path/home/node_modules/nodebin/node'
```

Unsure how I would be able to pull through an update when this missing file error occurs no matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching and trying different options the best one that worked for me was installing [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) and using that to update node instead, which worked without error.

Comment: @RahalKanishka Cant mark my own answer before 2 days is up, I will after that